# Connect to a projector from MBP via network

Tags: macos, screen-sharing, projector

Is it possible to connect to a regular projector via network to present the screen?

I have a Windows machine, and it quite simply can be done there. I just enter the IP address of the projector and that's it.

And I was really surprised when I couldn't find it on my MBP. It feels like a basic functionality, it should be there, but I can't find it.

That's so weird, especially when Apple releases the new MBP (or that MacBook with only one USB-C) without any video-port available, implying we should be "*wireless*". Well, I would like to, but can I really?

Comment: What projector are you using? The ability to do this is most likely because the projector supports a screen sharing method that's not available to your Mac. An AppleTV will get the job done if you can connect it to the projector then you can Airplay to it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an Apple TV. And that's the essence of the question - apparently Macs cannot connect to any proper projector via network. And that is such a shame.

Comment: But you can add an AppleTV to most any projector that has an HDMI input, but I'm assuming that's not an option. Still might be able to figure out how to stream to the projector if I knew what projector you were using....

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's not an option. When I visit different companies, they have different projectors in their offices, and my Windows 7 laptop has no problems connecting to any projector via network (out-of-the-box, it's a default functionality), however with my MBP I have to use HDMI cable (which is the reason why I prefer to use Windows laptop on my trips).

Comment: You're telling there's no common brand between these projectors, just any projector can be accessed on your Windows 7 laptop and streamed to with no software installed, just by browsing the network? That has not been my experienced with Windows computers and projectors in any office I've ever been in.

Comment: @ToddDabney, that's what I do experience. I connect to network and press Win + P.  If auto-discovery fails, I can connect directly by IP-address. So far it worked with different projector brands. Not having this on MBP is just frustrating.

Comment: The projectors you're using support some transport mechanism but I don't know what it is. Talk to the IT people at your org to figure that out and you might be able to find a software solution for your Mac that lets you do the same thing. I thought you might be using Miracast but that didn't get support from Windows until 8.1

Comment: Thing is: it works on my Windows 7 out-of-the-box, no software is needed to be installed. Here I'm just asking is it available on Mac OS as well (but apparently not and this is just sad). That's all.

Comment: @reif as far as I can tell these projectors support RDP which is a Microsoft specific protocol for sharing screens. Mac OSX supports VNC which is an open source standard protocol. Hence the reason this won't work out of the box. If you're willing to install a small piece of software you most likely can connect to these projectors. http://cord.sourceforge.net/